# angularjs html5mode in production as static files

Tags: angularjs

How can I use Amazon S3 servers to serve Angularjs as static files with `html5Mode(true)` ?

Been following this [blog](http://jjt.io/2013/11/16/angular-html5mode-using-yeoman-generator-angular/) but got stuck on pushing to production

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately (for the moment), it doesn't appear to be possible using native S3 tools.  Instead, I've been faking URL rewrites by actually copying `index.html` to any path used by angular.  Here's the script I'm using to automate the process (my folder structure is based on yeoman, hence the reason I'm using the `app/` and `dist/` folders)

```
rm -rf dist-html5mode
for ROUTE in $(grep when app/scripts/app.js | awk -F\' '{print $2}' | grep -v '^/$'); do
    echo $ROUTE
    mkdir -p dist-html5mode$(dirname $ROUTE)
    cp dist/index.html dist-html5mode$ROUTE
done
```

Now that you have a populated `dist-html5mode/` folder, upload its contents to the root of your S3 bucket and make sure you set the metadata `Content-Type` to `text/html`.